# Deselect jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

What is the best way to reset/refresh toggles? I am controlling some map layers with css styled selector. The Toggle All Off button deselects all map layers, but the toggles still show as 'active'. [Here is the example](http://erichsen-group.com/demoland/taylorpeterh/oilgasa10zzz33.html) (jfiddle doesn't like mapbox maps).

```
//Create toggles to turn map layers on and off
var item = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    link.href = '#';
    link.className == 'active';
    link.innerHTML = name;

link.onclick = function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

//turn off map layers when Toggle All Off button is clicked
    if ($(this).text() == 'Toggle All Off') {
        map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            map.removeLayer(layer);
        });

        map.addLayer(baseLayer);
    } else if (map.hasLayer(layer))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside if Toggle All Off

```
$('a.active').removeClass('active');
```

'a.active' selector will choose all links with class active and remove this class.

Answer (score 0):

```
function toggleClass(){
    if ($('a.active').length > 0){
        $('a.active').addClass('deactive');
        $('a.active').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $('a.deactive').addClass('active');
        $('a.deactive').removeClass('deactive');
    }
}
```